# Long pause after each iteration in Matlab loop

Tags: matlab, loops

I'm working with a Matlab script which loads a stack of images, processes and them stores them (see below). The script runs fine, but it has long pauses (about one hour for each step) between each step of the main loop. Do you have any suggestion on how to make it run smoothly?

```
clear;
number_projections = 40; 
number_images_per_projection = 1386; 
offset = 5;
OB=zeros([number_images_per_projection 512 512]);
IM=zeros([number_images_per_projection 512 512]);

m = 0;
for j = 14:number_projections
    for k = 1:number_images_per_projection
      % Lets load the OB images
      t = sprintf('/data/alcer/Data_analysis/BL18_May2014/19_Nickel/Simulated_OB/OB_%03i_%05i.fits',j-1, k-1);
      m = m + 1;
      OB(m,:,:) = fitsread(t);
      % And now the corrected images
      u = sprintf('/data/alcer/Beamtimes/Data_BL18_May2014/MCP_detector/19_Nickel_1/Corrected/Ni_corrected_all/Nickel_1_%03i_%05i.fits',j-1, k-1);
      IM(m,:,:) = fitsread(u);
    end
    %Let's use a rolling median (5 images before and 5 after)

    rolling_median_IM = zeros([512 512]);
    rolling_median_OB = zeros([512 512]);
    clean_images = zeros([512 512]);

    for k = offset+1:number_images_per_projection-offset
        rolling_interval_IM = squeeze(IM(k-offset:1:k+offset,:,:));        
        rolling_interval_OB = squeeze(OB(k-offset:1:k+offset,:,:));
        rolling_median_IM(:,:) = squeeze(median(rolling_interval_IM,1));
        rolling_median_OB(:,:) = squeeze(median(rolling_interval_OB,1));
        clean_images(:,:) = ((squeeze(OB(k,:,:)))./squeeze(rolling_median_OB(:,:)))-((squeeze(IM(k,:,:)))./squeeze(rolling_median_IM(:,:)));
        v = sprintf('/data/alcer/Data_analysis/BL18_May2014/19_Nickel/Cleaned_images/Cleaned_Ni_%03i_%05i.fits',j-1, k-1);
        fitswrite(clean_images, v);
    end
end
```

Comment: Clear the `rolling_median_IM` and `rolling_median_OB` from workspace (using `clear` command) before exiting the for loop. Also, after you do this, check where exactly the pause occur (using debugger). We will be able to help you more if we know where the problem occurs as we don't have your image data files. Do this and let us know :) P.S. remember that you are writing big chunks of data using `fitswrite` :)

Comment: Thanks @hagubear! I included your suggestions and I'm now using 'profile' to find the reason for the delay. I know I'm writing tons of data, but there's no way around for that ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [profile](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) tool to find out which bit of the code is causing the delay.